# Using Firebird Trace and Audit service for database replication

Tags: replication, firebird

Firebird supports [Trace and Audit](https://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/pmwiki.php?n=Doc.TraceAndAudit) service since version 2.5.

Audit logs may configure to filter SQL statements that is useful for database replication.

Here is a sample log:

```
INSERT INTO RDB$BACKUP_HISTORY(RDB$BACKUP_ID, RDB$TIMESTAMP, RDB$BACKUP_LEVEL, RDB$GUID, RDB$SCN, RDB$FILE_NAME) VALUES(NULL, 'NOW', ?, ?, ?, ?)

param0 = integer, "0"
param1 = varchar(38), "{855507A3-C794-477C-7E8E-BF5381BB6132}"
param2 = integer, "39"
param3 = varchar(255), "r:\backup.nbk"
```

If we do a program to parse the committed `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements from log and replay these SQL statement on replicated database, it seems we can produce some kind replication strategy here.

However, I can't find any discussions using trace and audit service on database replication.  Is it advisable to do so?

Comment: You might get into trouble with ordering of transactions. I'd recommend asking on the firebird-devel mailinglist though. Also, be aware that Firebird 4 will have replication built-in and there are products built on top of Firebird that already provide replication for earlier versions. I wouldn't recommend building replication on top of something (trace) that wasn't intended for that purpose.